# How to monitor used memory and mail when it's above threshold?

Tags: linux, memory

I have a Linux server. I'd like to monitor the amount of memory usage and if it's above certain threshold (let's say, 512 MB), have it send an e-mail to the admin automatically.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain memory usage via `free` command. A little parsing of its output will give you the currently used memory :

```
free -m | awk '/buffers\/cache/ {print $3}'
```

Then, you can send an email using `mail` command (assuming the mail chain is already configured on you server) :

```
echo -e "Mail content." | mail -s "Subject" "destination@expample.com"
```

With this, you can write a little `sh` script checking memory usage and sending mail if needed :

```
#!/bin/sh
memuse=$(free -m | awk '/buffers\/cache/ {print $3}')
if [ $memuse -ge 512 ]; then
    message="RAM limit exceeded in server alpha.\nCurrent use is $memuse MiB."
    echo -e "$message" | mail -s "RAM monitoring" "admin@example.com"
fi
```

Now, you just need to run this script periodically. We can for example use `cron` to run it every minute, by adding to `/etc/crontab` :

```
* * * * * /root/ram_monitoring.sh
```

(assuming you saved the script to `/root/ram_monitoring.sh` and you have a working cron deamon.)

Comment: i'm getting "buffers/cache:" as the output of the first command. any idea?

Comment: Indeed, I had an error, it's not `$2` but `$3`, I'll correct.